# Spring not able to locate JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-java-config

Using JavaConfig I have a problem locating the `@Repository` Spring beans.

The repository interface is defined like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

The configuration is defined like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example")
public class SampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
```

the package structure looks like this:

```
com.example
     configuration
           SampleApplication
     repository
           UserRepository
```

In the log file I see that the Repository is **found** as a candidate for bean definition, but:

```
ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner | Ignored because not a concrete top-level class:
```

**Interesting fact**

if I move the SampleApplication class to the `com.example` package, everything starts to work.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Although it's almost certainly not related, you do not need the `@Repository` annotation on `UserRepository`. Spring Data creates repositories that extend CrudRepository and are within the packages you have stated in your configuration

Comment: @geoand thanks for the hint. I was just trying to get things working

Comment: No problem! I wish I had some more insight on the problem. Perhaps you should also add the Spring Boot tag. You may draw some more attention to the problem

Comment: @geoand done. Although spring-boot tag has ~300 questions :(

Comment: I know, but there are plenty of people that keep an eye on those questions :)

Comment: @geoand If talking about spring-boot - everything seems really fine when you follow the **automagic** configuration path, but once you get your hands dirty, suddenly you realize that the whole application is falling apart just because you moved / renamed one single package.

Comment: Yes that seems very weird! I hope the good people that develop Spring Boot will check this one out and provide their insight!

Comment: Check out the answer by @Phil Webb. He is the co-creator of Spring Boot, so he definitely knows what he is talking about :)!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might need to use Spring Boot's `@EntityScan` annotation if your JPA entities are not in a sub-package of `com.example.configuration`. I would also recommend that you move your `@Configuration` off the `SpringBootServletInitializer` and into its own class.

If you can move your configuration class up a level you can drop the `@ComponentScan`, `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` annotations all together (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class)

If `@EntityScan` doesn't fix things perhaps you could provide an example project that we can look at?

Comment: I have multi-project setup where entities are on a separate project and repositories on others, @EntityScan is the only trick that helped, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem hear that using `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example")` the your context when start check for `com.example` as base package but it don't goes on. In other words the package scan will stop on the `com.example` level. For a deeper stanning, you have to do a things like this `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.**")`. However in this case the Spring data check all the package `com.example` and all the sub package. A more correct approch should be write a thik like this `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")` or `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository.**")`. In the first case you scan for the repository base package in the second case you scan for the repository and all sub package of repository that in my opinion is the correct approch for this kind of case.

I hope that this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I normally thought that the package you specify in @EnableJpaRepositories traverses the inner packages as well.

When in doubt, you could try the typesafe alternative:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackageClasses = {UserRepository.class})
public class SampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
```

Comment: Tried that with no success. The problem is that it finds the UserRepository as a bean candidate, but later it is being rejected. Furthermore, if I put the SampleApplication class in the com.example package, everything works out of the box

Comment: One question though: Why are you using the SpringBootServletInitializer as the main class?

Comment: I'm deploying to Tomcat, but I need an option to run the app in standalone mode for testing

Answer (score 0):

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories (basePackageClasses = {SchedulerRepository.class})
```

worked  for me in my case , though I had added all the annotations to pick up repository